# use an xcode layout constraint to place a display element within another display element

Tags: ios, xcode6, autolayout

The Apple Documentation has shown me how to place constraints between objects that are apart from each other in the view, like [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/UnderstandingAutolayout.html). However, what if you have a display element that is contained inside of another, as shown below:

[image: auto layout example from xcode 6]

Is it possible to set constraints that will "trap" the gray square within the red square?

Comment: once you set the constraints for the red square. Place the Gray square inside the red and set the leading, trailing , top and bottom for gray square

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have set the necessary constraints for the red box and place the gray box inside the red box.

[image]

[image]

Red box constraints:
In my case i want the red box in center of the screen with fixed width and height.

[image]

Gray box constraints:
Trapped inside the red box with the distance of 64 all side.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make the gray square a subview of the red square, then constrain it to the red square, which will be its superview.

The specific constraints would depend on how you wanted the gray square to size itself in relation to the red square.